# symfony which bundle I am running

Tags: php, symfony, routes, bundle

I am trying to create my first bundle in [Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html). The tutorial walks you through the process of creating a bundle called "Acme". Since I downloaded symfony 2.4 that went with the Acme Demo bundle. I changed all "AcmeBundle" to "myAcmeBundle". I created the controller, the route and the bundle exactly like the instruction except the name of the bundle.

The tut says that if I go to

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan
```

it should invoke my HelloController.php
My question is that how symfony knows which bundle I want to run. I have 2 bundles in my "src" folder now. and whenever I enter **localhost/app_dev.php/hello/Ryan** , it displays the content of HelloController.php in **AcmeBundle** (the default demo bundle). I want to display the content of HelloController.php in **myAcmeBundle** (my new created bundle).

Additional info:
     maybe something that has to do with the class AppKernel, but not very sure

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new myAcme\HelloBundle\myAcmeHelloBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            //$bundles[] = new myAcme\HelloBundle\myAcmeHelloBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

app\config\routing.yml

```
my_acme_hello:
    resource: "@myAcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

src\myAcme\HelloBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

```
my_acme_hello_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: myAcmeHelloBundle:Default:index }
```

Comment: You need to tweak the routing settings. Did you read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html) page?

Comment: Did you remove the routing entry at `src/Acme/HelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`? Whichever match is found first will be used to select a controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the "Hello" controller instead of "Default" controller

```
my_acme_hello_homepage:
    path:     /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: myAcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index }
```

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 routes are served (matched) in the same order that are parsed: when you use `prefix: /` without specify anything else (specially the test hello ruote) you're trying to override base `AcmeBundle` route that, I suppose without having enaugh information, is parsed BEFORE your new bundle route.

Solution: try for a moment to unregister `AcmeBundle` and see what happens.
If now the framework serves your newbundle ruote and you want to keep `AcmeBundle` alive, you should write the routes of your bundle BEFORE AcmeDemo ones

## Update

To unregister AcmeDemoBundle, Modify your `AppKernel` as follows:

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
  //$bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
  $bundles[] = new myAcme\HelloBundle\myAcmeHelloBundle();
  $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
  $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
  $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
}
```

Comment: hi, sorry i am new to symfony. how to unregister a bundle?